# How to find Matrix using properties of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

given

$$A=
  \begin{bmatrix}
   2  &  3 \\
   2  &  4 \\
  \end{bmatrix}
$$

$$C=
  \begin{bmatrix}
   2  &  -1 \\
   -1  &  1 \\
  \end{bmatrix}
$$

$$ A^{-1}B^{T}C^{-1} =
  \begin{bmatrix}
   1  &  1 \\
   0  &  3 \\
  \end{bmatrix}
$$

How to find matrix for B ? Can anyone help me

Comment: What happens if you multiply the last expression on the left by $A?$

Comment: $B=(AA^{-1}B^TC^{-1}C)^T$. Do the multiplication, take the transpose, and you're done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know $A$, $C$, and $A^{-1}B^TC^{-1}$ and we want to find $B$. Set $D =A^{-1}B^TC^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 3 \end{bmatrix}$. With some algebraic manipulations, we see that
\begin{align} 
A^{-1}B^T C^{-1} &= D \\
AA^{-1}B^T C^{-1} &= AD \\
B^T C^{-1} &= AD \\
B^T C^{-1}C &= ADC \\
B^T &= ADC \\
(B^T)^T &= (ADC)^T \\
B &= C^T D^T A^T.
\end{align}
I will leave it to you to compute $B = C^T D^T A^T$ :)